# Не могу сделать вкладку внутри виджета

Tags: python, pyqt5, виджет

Пытаюсь сделать вкладки внутри выдвигающегося виджета, однако все идет не по плану и я не понимаю почему, помогите пожалуйста

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

#класс с основным окном и выдвигающимся виджетом
class gg(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 
        MainWindow.setObjectName('ОКОШЕЧКО')
        #размер основного окна
        MainWindow.resize(850, 500)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccffbd;') 
        self.widget.setObjectName('widget')
        
        
        #создаем виджет справа
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)                      
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 500))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background: #7eca9c;")                  
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")

        #попытка сделать вкладку
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('1'),
            '2')
        self.tab1.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('3'),
            '4')
        self.tab1.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft)
        self.tab1.setCurrentIndex(0)

        #попытка указать кнопку открытия другой вкладки в виджете frame2
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.tab1)
        
   

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):             
        pass




#создаем класс, который наследуется от виджета и заполняем его минимальной логикой
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, gg):
    
    def __init__(self): 
                   
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
##        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
##        self.btn.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.frame2.installEventFilter(self)                                    
        #устанавливаем размер виджета ДО и ПОСЛЕ анимации
        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(50, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(200, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)
    #функция с анимацией выдвижения виджета путем наведения курсора
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
#        if self.btn is checked:  
        if self.frame2 is obj: 
            #анимация выдвижения                                                                            
            if event.type() == event.Enter:                                   
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            #анимация закрытия виджета
            elif event.type() == event.Leave:                                  
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
             
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    p = MainWindow()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем понял, но чтобы разместить QTabWidget внутри вашего выдвигающегося виджета:

```
self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.widget)
```

Однако, по умолчанию он будет постоянно включен.

Попробуйте понять, когда вы хотите видеть вкладки, а когда их надо скрыть:

```
self.tab1.hide()
self.tab1.show()
```

Помните, что функции можно вызывать после выполнения анимации:

```
self._animation.finished.connect(lambda: print('Какая-то функция'))
```

И в процессе выполнения анимации:

```
self._animation.valueChanged.connect(lambda: print('Какая-то функция'))
```

Comment: Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку(ну в моем случае на виджет) QTabWidget появлялся в основном окне, а не в выдвигающимся виджете, но не понимаю как можно это сделать